# Tensorflow: Create a matrix using multiple tf.concat

Tags: matrix, tensorflow, concatenation

I would like to create a 2-D matrix in tensoflow concatenating multiple 1-D arrays produced by a for-loop. 
Let's say, for example, that in every loop is produced an array of shape = (1,5) full of ones ([1,1,1,1,1]).
What i need to get finally ater 3 loops is:

```
[[1,1,1,1,1]
  [1,1,1,1,1]
  [1,1,1,1,1]]
```

I actually need a solution that adds a new row in the matrix in every single loop. How to create that with tensorflow? I thought of the tf.concat but, where i cannot think where to save the value of the matrix during the loops.

Comment: Are you always going to have 3 loops?

Comment: I am always going to have a specific number of loops, yes!

Comment: added an answer, let me know if you need something more general

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it. You could also add your own answer if the existing one is incomplete / incorrectv @Cfis Yoi

Answer (score 2):

If you have a large number of loops, you will need to concat the arrays. Let's start with your first vector `v1` having just one dimension. Begin by reshaping it to dimensions `(1, vector_size)` using [`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape).

```
v1 = tf.reshape(v1, [1, vector_size])
```

Now you can do the same for vector `v2` and use [`tf.concat()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#concat) to join the two arrays along `axis=0`.

```
v1 = tf.concat(0, [v1, v2])
```

Note i've reused `v1` here. This will be in your loop and `v2` will be the new variable.

---

If instead you have a fixed smaller number of arrays (loops in the context of the question), you can do this via [`tf.stack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#stack).

Let's say your first loop produces array `v1`, second `v2` and third `v3`.
You can use `tf.stack()` as follows,

```
result = tf.stack([v1, v2, v3])
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ask the right question. My problem is exactly this vi. Let's say the number of the loops is N, where N could be very big. I would like a solution that adds a new row in the matrix in every single loop.

Comment: Is this more helpful?

Comment: I have a noob question:
If I do this while creating my computational graph, for example calculate some embeddings in a for loop and use stack to get a matrix, will the backprop still work fine?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you use a loop to make a series of connections in the graph, it will still backpropagate

Answer (score 1):

What you want may be `tf.tile`, and below is the example:

```
a = tf.reshape(tf.range(10), (-1, 10))
b = tf.tile(a, (5, 1))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(a))
    print(sess.run(b))
```